# Correct usage of "rm" to remove files matching a pattern

Tags: wildcards, rm

If I want to use the `rm` command to remove all files with the `.log` extension from a directory, how can I do that?

I tried - `rm * .log` , but I don't know if it works.

Comment: In many cases you can _more safely_ test a command by prefacing it with `echo`. In this instance you could `echo rm * .log` to see an approximation to the command that would be executed. (This is safe to try. Unlike your own command.)

Comment: or I use `ls`, and when I'm sure I use `rm`.

Comment: The interactive option `rm -i *.log` can be a lifesaver, too.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to remove the space between `*` and `.log`. The command line uses something called globbing. `*` is a wildcard for any string of characters. So by running `rm *.log` you are saying remove all files that end with `.log`.

Always be careful using wild cards as you could unintentionally be running a command on files you do not want to run the command on.